# Find similar customers through customer attributes

Tags: node.js, relationships, nearest-neighbor

We run a webshop where we want to give customers advice what to buy.
Therefore we want to give customers suggestions and advice what kind of product they could buy in our shop based on some input from our customers.

For this we want to make a small application in NodeJS which will connect to our database.

To determine this product advice we want to define and collect several custom customer attributes.

Each attribute has a value from [1-10] which will say something about the customer. For example from a customer likes colourful clothing on a scale of 1-10

*Example Customer Data:*

```
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|            | attr_1 | attr_2 | attr_3 | attr_4 |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Customer 1 |    2   |   10   |    3   |    2   |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Customer 2 |    8   |    3   |    4   |    4   |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Customer 3 |    5   |    2   |    3   |    9   |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Customer 4 |    4   |    2   |    1   |    4   |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Customer 5 |    3   |    8   |    2   |    2   |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

We want to find which customers are similar to each other.

*Input:*

```
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Customer x |    7   |    3   |    4   |    4   |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

*Output:*

```
"Most Similar To Customer 2"
```

And based on the order history of *customer 2* (and other similar customers) we want to give a personalized product advice.

**Are there any best practises, techniques (I read about nearest neighbour algorithms), or data comparison packages or techniques which could help us further finding related customers?**

Comment: You could loop through every item and calculate their similarities one by one then pick the customer that is most similar

Comment: this is a simplified display of our customer data. What to do if you have thousands of entities and a big amount of attributes as well? Then it wouldn't be efficient anymore I guess? Is there any algorithm which could solve this issue?

Comment: you probably wont find an algorithm to solve your issue, at best you could pre compute how similar each customer is to another but even at 10000 users we would be near 100 million similarity ratings. A better option and this is the one that i would recommend would be to categorize people egg customer x likes hates brown shoes and likes the color red then store that in a db where all people in that category would be similar. One final method you could use would be to simply run a db query for each parameter and see which customer comes up the most often

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cluster analysis to identify natural segments exist in your data and then whenever you have new customer entry we can use the train model to assign the new customer into appropriate segment. And based on segmentation you can plan what you want to recommend to the customer.